# Replace \n from textarea with "invisible" line break in console

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, textarea

`console.log('Hello\nworld');` outputs:

```
Hello
world
```

If I write "Hello[ENTER_KEY]world" into a `<textarea>`, then `console.log($('textarea').html())` outputs:

```
Hello\nworld
```

How can I convert this so that `\n` isn't printed but shown as a line break in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use textarea **value** property as below:

```js
function myFunction(){
console.log(document.getElementById('myTextArea').value);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextArea" onchange="myFunction()"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try getting `value` instead of `innerHTML`

```js
console.log($('textarea').val());
```